# Functions - Set Theory Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $f$ be a function from $X$ to $Y$, and let $A$, $B$ be subsets (non-proper) of $X$. For each of the following statements, either prove the statement or else give a counter example:
>
> a.) $f(X\setminus A)=Y\setminus f(A)$
>
> b.) $f(X\setminus A) \subseteq Y\setminus f(A)$
>
> c.) $Y\setminus f(A) \subseteq f(X\setminus A)$
>
> d.) $f(A\cup B) = f(A)\cup f(B)$
>
> e.) $f(A) \cap f(B) = f(A \cap B)$

I have an exam tomorrow and have been lagging on the set theory.

Much appreciated.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 You can help through MSE, can't you?

Comment: @Peter Ok,fine.Gee,a guy's gotta eat in these tough times-can't fault me for trying............LOL

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 No comments.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 : Advertising for your professional services is usually called "spam".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it consists of multiple, largely unrelated questions at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) False If $A \subsetneq X$, consider the constant function.

b) False Use $(a)$

c) False. Suppose $f$ is not surjective. Suppose $Y$ contains more than one element and $f$ is a content function.

d) True. Suppose $x \in f(A \cup B)$, then $x = f(y)$ for $y \in A$ or $y \in B$ so $x \in f(A)$ or $x \in f(B)$. Suppose $x \in f(A) \cup f(B)$. Then $x \in f(A)$ or $x \in f(B)$. So there exists a $y \in A$ or a $y \in B$ such that $f(y) = x$ so $x \in f(A \cup B)$.

e) True. You wrote $f(A) \cap f(B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$. Do you mean $f(A) \cap f(B) = f(A \cap B)$??? If you meant the latter, this is false. Suppose $f$ is a constant function and $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Comment: Damn,beat me to it,had a feeling someone would. Nice job,BTW.

Comment: For (c), what happens if instead of being content, $f$ is unhappy with its lot in life? (-;

Comment: e.) Yes! That is what I meant.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sometimes the autocorrect gets it wrong. I am going to leave it like that so your comment makes sense.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 You should just post answer anyway. A quality answer is sometimes more desirable than the first answer.

Comment: @William: If you edit, I'll remove the comment. I was just trying to point out a small error in a way that was (I hope at least mildly) amusing.

Comment: Thank you! Where should I go to learn to input my questions in the best notation?

Comment: @Joshua: Look at the answers to [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).